# How to find out under which Attribute Group the 2 data extensions are mapped?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder, data-designer

I am inside the Journey and DE is the entry source.
There is a filter applied in Decision split known as  ‘double_opt_in’ (can be true or false).

This ‘double_opt_in’ field is not in Entry source DE, but some other DE.
This journey was created by someone else in the past.
(I know that in order access fields not available  in entry source DE we need to do linking within  a Attribute Group in Data Designer )

My question is, How to know which is the attribute group in which these 2 DE are linked in Data Designer? There are several Attribute groups in Data Designer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the requirement given that you need to find out the attribute group name to which ‘double_opt_in’ field belongs, In order to do that you can follow below steps -

1. Click on 'Decision Split'.
2. Click on the Field name under filter criteria.
3. You should see the Path given at the top of it (It shows the name of attribute group and name of DE as well).

Also, in order to use the column as contact data in Journey, this should be part of attribute group but not necessarily be linked with Journey Data Extension.

How this works is -

When a contact will enter into a Journey, it must have a contact id and this contact id will be used to lookup the data to the DE in attribute groups.

Hope this helps.